# Gauss seidel iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to find the guass iteration for 4 x 4 matrix. I have written below code but the problem is it is giving correct response for 3 x 3 matrix but failing for 4 x 4.
I do not know where it is going wrong.

def gauss_seidel_iterations(a_matrix, x_matrix ,b_matrix):

```
iterations = len(a_matrix)    

for i in range(0, iterations):        
    d = b_matrix[i]                  

    for j in range(0, iterations):     
        if(i != j):
            d-=a_matrix[i][j] * x_matrix[j]

    x_matrix[i] = d / a_matrix[i][i]

return x_matrix
```

Comment: Please also provide your input(s) and - if possible - your expected output(s).

Comment: I used a random matrix, a_matrix = 4 x 4, b_matrix = 4 x 1 and x_matrix = 4 x 1

Comment: On wikipedia, there is a python implementation of the 'Gauss-Seidel' method. Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method

Comment: So when people answer your questions, you [delete the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72668272/5459839)?